# Android Cursor with ORMLite to use in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, android-cursor, android-cursoradapter

Is there any way to get Cursor for a query, which I am processing with ORMLite Dao object?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) now supports `next()`, `previous()`, `moveRelative(offset)`, ... methods on the [`CloseableIterator` class](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/CloseableIterator.html).  This should allow you to move the underlying `Cursor` object around at will.

It also supports the following DAO Cursor methods:

- [`dao.mapSelectStarRow(databaseResults)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#mapSelectStarRow%28com.j256.ormlite.support.DatabaseResults%29) Return the latest row from the database results from a query to `select *`.  With this you can change the cursor location (for example) and then get the current object.
- [`dao.getSelectStarRowMapper()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getSelectStarRowMapper%28%29) Provides a mapper that you can use to map the object outside of the Dao.

---

When you are building your own query with [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), you use the `QueryBuilder` object.  `queryBuilder.prepare()` returns a `PreparedQuery` which is used by various methods in the DAO.  You can call `dao.iterator(preparedQuery)` which will return a `CloseableIterator` which is used to iterate through the results.  There is a `iterator.getRawResults()` to get access to the `DatabaseResults` class. Under Android, this can be cast to an `AndroidDatabaseResults` which has a `getCursor()` method on it to return the Android `Cursor`.

Something like the following code:

```
// build your query
QueryBuilder<Foo, String> qb = fooDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where()...;
// when you are done, prepare your query and build an iterator
CloseableIterator<Foo> iterator = dao.iterator(qb.prepare());
try {
   // get the raw results which can be cast under Android
   AndroidDatabaseResults results =
       (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
   Cursor cursor = results.getRawCursor();
   ...
} finally {
   iterator.closeQuietly();
}
```

This is a bit complicated but you are *definitely* having to peer behind the vale to get to this object which is hidden by the database abstraction classes.

Comment: how can i obtain the databaseConnection?

Comment: I've changed this answer to show how it can be done without needed the database connection.

Comment: @Gray What is the best way to inflate the list_item views using the cursor?  Also, is a `CursorAdapter` the best thing to use with `OrmLiteBaseListActivity`?

Comment: Sorry @mattblang.  I'm not an Android developer.  I'd ask that question on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-android

Comment: @Gray your contribution on SO specifically regarding ORMLite is much appreciated, tnx

Comment: @Gray when using this strategy in and handing the cursor off to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` or `CursorAdapter` subclass of my own used with an Android Grid/ListView, I get a `StaleDataException` -- I noticed commenting out the `iterator.closeQuietly()` prevents this from happening. What would you suggest to work-around this -- apart from keeping the iterator around until I'm done with the cursor?

Comment: @Mark Yes, same problem here.  What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `getHelper()` method to reach the dao methods create etc. you only have to inherit from the `OrmLiteBaseActivity<YourDBHelper>` and you can call it. It will look sth like this:

```
public class YourClass extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<YourDBHelper> {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     getHelper().getDao().queryForAll();
     ...
  }
}
```

If you mean the cursor to handle database operation: I don't think that you can reach it! But I don't understand why you should need it. ORMLite has nearly all functions of the cursor. So what do you need it for?

Comment: I know about this, but I need to get Cursor to use it in CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some of Gray's advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416964/ormlite-with-cursoradapter-in-android) post? He explains how you can select a column as another name, such as, select id as _id.

Comment: Since you can name your columns in ormlite I guess why not just name them _id, rather than doing the select as :) ?

Comment: Sure, you can, but in an instance where renaming them is not an option, you simply use the sql syntax of "as";)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an Activity and don't want to mess around with the QueryBuilder give the following a go, which is just as effective.

```
Cursor cursor = getHelper().getReadableDatabase().query(tableName, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder)
```