# Get a cursor with a raw sql with ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'd like to use a SimpleCursorAdapter with a Spinner.

I found how to return a Cursor.

```
QueryBuilder<ChoixPointVerification, Integer> qb = choixPointVerificationDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq(FIELD, id);
PreparedQuery<ChoixPointVerification> preparedQuery = qb.prepare();
AndroidCompiledStatement compiledStatement =
                (AndroidCompiledStatement)preparedQuery.compile(db, StatementType.SELECT);

Cursor cursor = compiledStatement.getCursor();
return cursor;
```

But the Spinner require a _id field and I'll only have an object with an id field. I prefer to avoid the rename of the field.

How can I resolve that case ? I really need to associate an id to all spinner field.

I imagined that I can maybe issue a cursor from a rawsql but I din't find how with ormlite. It seems to be possible if I can create a PreparedQuery with a raw sql.

I also read that if I have an AndroidDatabase object I can issue a Cursor object but how can we create an AndroidDatabase with ormlite ?

I'm really open with all the solution

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I just found a solution which seems to be efficient, simple, and compliant with ormlite.

I just have to get an `AndroidDatabase` with `getHelper().getReadableDatabase()`.

and then use

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("choixpointverification",
    new String[] { "id", "id as _id", "nom" },
    "masque = 0 and idPointVerification = " + idPointVerification.toString(),
    null, null, null, "tri");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the underlying `Cursor` object from [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) by using `QueryBuilder` without having to resort to a raw query.  Take a look at this answer:

> [Android Cursor with ORMLite to use in CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159816/android-cursor-with-ormlite-to-use-in-cursoradapter/7161169#7161169)

You can do something like the following code:

```
// build your query
QueryBuilder<Foo, String> qb = fooDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where()...;
// when you are done, prepare your query and build an iterator
CloseableIterator<Foo> iterator = dao.iterator(qb.prepare());
try {
   // get the raw results which can be cast under Android
   AndroidDatabaseResults results =
       (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
   Cursor cursor = results.getRawCursor();
   ...
} finally {
   iterator.closeQuietly();
}
```

Comment: When I use this code for a `SimpleCursorAdapter` I get a `StaleDataException` due to the call `iterator.closeQuietly()`.  For now I just commented that line out, but I am afraid that will create a memory leak.