# Problems getting Android Cursor from an DAOObject with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite, android-cursor

I am trying to retrieve a Cursor from a ORMLite PreparedQuery.
My goal is to only paginate my results query, so the device memory won't be too overloaded.
I've read Gray's guides on how to use the QueryBuilder object [Android Cursor with ORMLite to use in CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159816/android-cursor-with-ormlite-to-use-in-cursoradapter).
Also this one [ORMLite with CursorAdapter in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416964/ormlite-with-cursoradapter-in-android).
But when I try to do: "iterator.getRawResults();"  well, the iterator class don't recognize the getRawResults method. It just supports the common methods close(), getEquals(), next(), and so on...

I can retrieve e list of objects successfully from my query, so it isn't a empty query problem...

am I missing something ?
My pom.xml is attached.

Here is the test with a list of Objects

```
public List<Produto> getProdutoDecricao2(String padrao) throws SQLException {

    List<Produto> listaProduto = null;
    QueryBuilder<Produto, String> queryBuilder = produtoDao.queryBuilder();
    Where<Produto, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
    SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
    selectArg.setValue('%'+padrao+'%');
    where.like("descricao", selectArg);

    PreparedQuery<Produto> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();      
    listaProduto = produtoDao.query(preparedQuery);

    return listaProduto;

}
```

My failed attempt with Cursors...

```
//creation of DAO
private Dao<Produto,String> produtoDao;

public Cursor getProdutoDecricao(String padrao)  {
    List<Produto> listaProduto = null;
    QueryBuilder<Produto, String> queryBuilder = produtoDao.queryBuilder();
    Where<Produto, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
    SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
    selectArg.setValue('%'+padrao+'%');
    where.like("descricao", selectArg);

// when you are done, prepare your query and build an iterator
    PreparedQuery<Produto> preparedQuery =  queryBuilder.prepare();
    CloseableIterator<Produto> iterator = produtoDao.iterator(preparedQuery);

    AndroidDatabaseResults results = (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
    Cursor cursor = results.getRawCursor();

    iterator.close();


    return cursor;

    }
```

Here is the project pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <android-platform>8</android-platform>
    <android-maven-plugin-version>3.4.0</android-maven-plugin-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin-version>2.8</maven-eclipse-plugin-version>
    <org.codehaus.jackson-version>1.9.7</org.codehaus.jackson-version>
</properties>

<repositories>         
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>         <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${android-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android-platform}</platform>
                    <path>/Users/rav/Documents/Android/android-sdk-macosx</path>
                </sdk>
                <emulator>
                    <avd>Android4.1</avd>
                </emulator>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jgilfelt.android-viewbadger</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-viewbadger</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Using Jackson for JSON marshaling -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT
Well, first i was using version 4.9 of ORMLite with isn't really official, and didn't have the methods I wanted to use. After I changed my pom.xml to use android-4.42 and core-4.42 Maven  didn't let me compile the program, giving the Dalvik error (“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”) despite of my attempts to solve this problem, I  couldn't.

I created a new project in a new workspace without Maven and added the libs manually, now everything works fine. It seems to be a Maven problem.
I hope it helps someone.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to do: "iterator.getRawResults();" well, the iterator class don't recognize the getRawResults method.

I'm confused by this.  [`CloseableIterator`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/CloseableIterator.html#getRawResults%28%29) has supported this method since version 4.30.  You may need to upgrade to a more recent version.

```
AndroidDatabaseResults results =
    (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
Cursor cursor = results.getRawCursor();
```

You say that this is a failed attempt but the code is correct.  Please let me know what exceptions you are getting or what problems you are seeing and I can address them.

Comment: It displays a error : The method getRawCursor() is undefined for the type AndroidDatabaseResults.

A i'm using version 4.9 of ormlite-android.

Comment: @Anika, as my answer mentions, you will need to upgrade to at least 4.30 of ORMLite to get these methods.

Comment: I've changed my dependencies in the pom.xml archive to the version 4.42 of ormlite-android and ormlite-core, my classes are recognizing everything, thanks. But now i got the following error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.

Comment: Not sure about that error @Anika.  Seems like an android thing.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation Gray :)

Comment: Well, the only I achieved to make it work was to create a new workspace and then a new project WITHOUT MAVEN and add the libs I wanted to my class path. Now everything works perfect.

Comment: Huh.  I used ORMLite all of the time with Maven.   I wonder what the problem is with your config @Anika.