# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist with Ormlite cursor

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite with `CursorLoader`, using the [ormlite-extras](https://github.com/campnic/ormlite-android-extras) library (I use the package `support.extras` as I intend to target android 2.2 and up).

I have the following exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:344)
    at rainstudios.meleo.ui.eventlv.EventLvFragment.onLoadFinished(EventLvFragment.java:274)
    at rainstudios.meleo.ui.eventlv.EventLvFragment.onLoadFinished(EventLvFragment.java:1)
    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:427)
    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:395)
    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:103)
    at rainstudios.meleo.data.RainstudiosOrmliteCursorLoader.deliverResult(RainstudiosOrmliteCursorLoader.java:68)
    at rainstudios.meleo.data.RainstudiosOrmliteCursorLoader.deliverResult(RainstudiosOrmliteCursorLoader.java:1)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:221)
    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)
    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I did some digging and noticed that indeed `'_id'` is not present in the `results` returned by the code in the CursorLoader.

For more information, please see the code above :

```
/* Runs on a worker thread */
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        CloseableIterator<T> iterator = mDao.iterator(mQuery);

        // get the raw results which can be cast under Android
        AndroidDatabaseResults results = (AndroidDatabaseResults) iterator
                .getRawResults();
        cursor = results.getRawCursor();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        // Ensure the cursor window is filled
        cursor.getCount();
        registerContentObserver(cursor, mObserver);
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Using the debugger, it appears the following :

```
results.columnNameMap = [id, code, name, popular, rating, voteCount, shortDescription, description, hoursDescription, url, modificationDate, syncDate, artist_id, district_id, pictures, frontPicture, userRating, venue_id, userComment, userFavorite, situation_id, caFrontPictureId, caResources]

results.columnNames = {syncDate=11, userRating=16, district_id=13, pictures=14, userFavorite=19, artist_id=12, code=1, situation_id=20, frontPicture=15, voteCount=5, url=9, caResources=22, id=0, hoursDescription=8, userComment=18, shortDescription=6, description=7, popular=3, name=2, venue_id=17, rating=4, caFrontPictureId=21, modificationDate=10}
```

The creation of the prepared query is pretty standard :

```
public PreparedQuery<EventDb> findAllEventsQuery() {
    try {

        QueryBuilder<EventDb, Integer> eventQb = getEventDao()
                .queryBuilder();
        return eventQb.prepare();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Out.handleSilentError("Cannot retrieve all events", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I did the test executing the query and getting the results as a List : everything works alright.

For now, I'm puzzled.

Besides, I have another for the ormlite experts.

- Am I supposed to close the iterator by calling `iterator.closeQuietly()` ?

Comment: Look at this question to see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416964/ormlite-with-cursoradapter-in-android

Comment: Change the column name id to be _id

Comment: Did you figure this out dude?  Does renaming the `id` field to be `_id` work?  I think that's a limitation of the `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: @Gray : do I need to open an request to improve Cursor ?

Comment: Sure.  Or send mail on the android mailing list.  Or forward to me a previous email that I ignored @Nameiscarl.

Comment: @patheticpat : if you create an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @patheticpat, the solution is available on stackoverflow : [ORMLite with CursorAdapter in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416964/ormlite-with-cursoradapter-in-android)

Your id fields **need** to be mapped to a column named _id to use Cursor with `Ormlite` 4.42.

Like this :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "event")
public class EventDb extends BaseDaoEnabled<EventDb, Integer> {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
    int id;
```

Note : And you can't call `iterator.closeQuietly()` because it crashes.
I hope that there is no memory leaked because if that.