# Ormlite, listViews and adapters?

Tags: android, android-listview, ormlite

I have OrmLite running in my app with database helpers and so forth. I have looked in the OrmLite's examples and some tutorials. This is my code for using listViews:

Database manager:

```
public List<Artist> getAllArtists() {
    List<Artist> artists = null;
    try {
        artists = getHelper().getArtistDao().queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return artists;
}
```

Activity:

```
List<Artist> artists = dataBase.getAllArtists(); 

for (Artist artist : artists) {
     items.add(artist);
}

mAdapter = new ArtistsListCustomAdapter(getActivity(), items);
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Is this an ok way or will there be trouble down the road using my method?

From other sources I have read that should use `CursorAdapter` for listViews and not the BaseAdapter (which I am now extending in `ArtistsListCustomAdapter()`). To me it seems awkward to iterate over the result a second time to create the array.

I have found some clues regarding using adapters this but since I am rather new to Android in general, I would really appreciate more clues to "connect the dots". In my case, should `getAllArtists()` return a `Cursor`? It seems complicated for such an easy task:

> [Android Cursor with ORMLite to use in CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159816/android-cursor-with-ormlite-to-use-in-cursoradapter)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this:

https://github.com/campnic/ormlite-android-extras

They have implementation of ormlite cursor adapter.