# ORMLite union operator

Tags: android, ormlite

I have three tables that I have to present in one Android `ListView`.  To get the data I use the SQL `UNION` operator to "merge" all three tables together, so that in my ViewBinder I can make each timeline item look distinct.

These items need to be sorted in chronological order. These three tables do not have a common base class.

Here is the SQL that I have in mind:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id, startTime as time, username, comment, "CustomerInteraction" FROM CustomerInteraction  
        UNION 
        SELECT id, date as time, "" as username, "" as comment, "Sale" FROM Sale
        UNION 
        SELECT id, claimDate as time, username, comment,  "TravelClaim" FROM TravelClaim) 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 100
```

How can I express the above query in ORMLite?

I know I can use `Dao.executeRaw`, but I don't want to populate my entire list in one go.  I would much rather use the [trick to get the underlying cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159816) from ORMLite, and then just pass that to my Adapter. (Lazy loading, makes initial display of long lists much faster.)

Is there a way I can do something like `Dao.getPreparedQueryFromRaw(String statement)` ?  Or better yet `QueryBuilder.union(QueryBuilder qb)`?

Comment: "I don't want to populate my entire list in one go [...] Lazy loading" I am not sure you can achieve this easily. If you use ListView and CursorAdapter, the entire list is queried. There is no pagination/limit. The recycling stuff of ListView is purely on the views, not on the underlying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can do something like Dao.getPreparedQueryFromRaw(String statement) ? Or better yet QueryBuilder.union(QueryBuilder qb)?

The best way to do this with ORMLite is with one of the the [`queryRaw(...)` methods](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).  They return a [`GenericRawResults` class](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/GenericRawResults.html) which you can iterate across.  The iterator gives you a [number of different methods](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/CloseableIterator.html) to help with moving around the list.

The problem is that the generic results are not of a certain type so I'm not sure if you can map it into the Android `ListView`.  You can provide a [RawRowMapper](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapper.html) to `queryRaw(...)`.  You can get the mapper for a particular type by using the [`dao.getRawRowMapper()` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#getRawRowMapper%28%29).

Hope something here is helpful.

Comment: I'll see if it will work to create a Cursor that wraps a `RawRowMapper` to make it work with a `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a Cursor by calling rawQuery on the SQLiteDatabase. I do something like this:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = getHelper().getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(MY_SQL_QUERY, null);
```

You don't need to do anything much more than that.

Comment: That would work, yes, but I would prefer an ORMLite centric solution.  Nowhere else in our code do we use raw SQL, so to put it here, would be nasty.