# ORM Lite with ListView and Mysql backend (android)

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to build an android application which shows a list of database entries in a ListView.

I came across to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159816/android-cursor-with-ormlite-to-use-in-cursoradapter) and tried the following

```
CloseableIterator<Parlor> iterator = new ParlorAsync().execute().get();
AndroidDatabaseResults adr = (AndroidDatabaseResults) iterator.getRawResults();
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_view_template,
                adr.getRawCursor(),
                new String[]{""},
                new int[]{R.id.parlor_name});
parlor_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where parlor is an entity and ParlorAsync is a AsyncTask which handles the connection to the Mysql Database and returns every row in the database:

```
JdbcConnectionSource source = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/mydatabase");
source.setUsername("user");
source.setPassword("password");
Dao<Parlor, Integer> parlorDao = DaoManager.createDao(source, Parlor.class);
QueryBuilder<Parlor, Integer> queryBuilder = parlorDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.selectColumns("name");
queryBuilder.orderBy("name", true);
return parlorDao.iterator(queryBuilder.prepare());
```

As you can see I used a JdbcConnectionSource and this is where the problem begins. It now tells me

```
com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseResults cannot be cast to com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults
```

This is the list_view_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ParlorListView">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/parlor_name" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

These are my gradle dependencies

```
compile group: 'com.j256.ormlite', name: 'ormlite-core', version: '4.48'
compile group: 'com.j256.ormlite', name: 'ormlite-jdbc', version: '4.48'
compile group: 'com.j256.ormlite', name: 'ormlite-android', version: '4.48'
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your particular problem is trying to cast `DatabaseResults`
   interface to `AndroidDatabaseResults` hoping that it's workable -
   result shows that it's not
2. Your fundamental problem is trying to
   extract `Cursor` from `Iterator` which is also unreliable.

You should get `Cursor` from `ContentProvider` which has to be loaded using [LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) and your query should be placed where `query()` method of `ContentProvider` sits.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? I got a external mysql database (not local) and I managed to read/write using JdbcConnectionSource, but I still need to get a Cursor from this JdbcConnectionSource ...

Comment: You should wrap your jdbc queries with `CursorProvider` - that's it